# Fetch a subcollection from firestore as a list of objects

Tags: android, firebase, collections, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch a subcollection from Firestore as a list of objects.

```kotlin
var areaList:ArrayList<AreaModel> = ArrayList<AreaModel>()
val querySnapshot = firestoreDB.collection("/cities/$city/areas").get()
if(!querySnapshot.result!!.isEmpty) {
      Result.success(querySnapshot.toObjects(ArrayList<AreaModel>()))
} else {
      Log.e("CITY_AREAS","fetching areas failed")
}
```

And I want to do it in a way that I return this list only when the fetch is complete.

**Note:** The current code throws an `Unresolved Reference toObjects`

Edit: 
AreaModel :

```kotlin
class AreaModel: BaseFirestoreDataModel {
    var geolocation: GeoPoint = GeoPoint(0.0,0.0)
    var name:String = ""
    constructor(
        geolocation: GeoPoint = GeoPoint(0.0,0.0),
        name: String =""
    ):super("locations"){
        this.geolocation=geolocation
        this.name=name
    }
}
```

and my dat structure : 
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the code sample?

Comment: @Hawklike it throws a "unresolved reference toObjects"

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and the content of your `AreaModel` class. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Firebase documentation, the function `toObjects` has the following syntax: `public List<T> toObjects (Class<T> clazz)`.

> Returns the contents of the documents in the QuerySnapshot, converted to the provided class, as a list.
>   Parameter: **clazz** - the POJO type used to convert the documents in the list.

Therefore you should pass ONLY class type as an argument, ie. `AreaModel::class.java` in your case. Furthermore, the function itself retrieves a list of objects of `AreaModel` class.